# Show that $d_H(A,B)=\max\{\sup_{a\in A}d(a,B),\sup_{b\in B}d(b,A)\}$ is finite if $A,B$ are bounded topologically

Tags: calculus, general-topology, functional-analysis

Show that $d_H(A,B)=\max\{\sup_{a\in A}d(a,B),\sup_{b\in B}d(b,A)\}$ is finite if $A,B$ are bounded topologically. A set $A\subset X$ in a metric space $(X,d)$ is called "bounded" if it is contained in a finite open ball in $X$.

I thought I was getting somewhere in my attempt but I believe there is something problematic in it:

Suppose to the contrary that there are $A,B$ bounded such that $d_H(A,B)=\infty$. WLOG assume that $d_H(A,B)=\sup_{a\in A}d(a,B)$.

Since $d(a,B)=\inf_{b\in B}d(a,b)\le d(a,b)$ for a random $b\in B$, $\infty=\sup_{a\in A}d(a,B)\le \sup_{a\in A}d(a,b)$ for an arbitrary $b$ now chosen as a constant variable.

That means there exists a sequence $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}\subset A$ such that $d(a_n,b)\to\infty$ as $n\to \infty$. **But** $A\subset B_{r}(x)$ and  therefore $d(a_n,b)\le d(a_n,x)+d(x,b)< r+d(x,b)<\infty$. It seemed okay until I noticed I haven't used the fact that $B$ is bounded. What is the problematic part of my attempt? How should I approach this question?

**Edit:** can I use a sequence of the form $(a_n,b_n)$? Would that be of use?

Comment: You don't use it because you assume only one of the suprema is infinite. This need not be the case, so you actually need to check for the case where the other one is $\infty$ as well, but that one is just analogous.

Comment: By that you say that I cannot use "WLOG"? Is it not applicable?

Comment: I took what you addressed into consideration and also thought about showing the other case in the same course of events, but the feeling it gives me is the same feeling I get when using the same equation twice...

Comment: Well, to me "WLOG" implies that only one of them is infinite. It might be better to just assume that one supremum is infinite, show by contradiction that it is not, then just state that the proof for the other one is analogous and say that that implies $d_H$ is finite.

Comment: Besides that, what is your perspective on the nature of my proof?

Comment: What is the part inflicted by the possibility that the other one is not infinite? This could help me see things clearer...

Comment: I think I know what the problem it: I took a specific $b$ for all $a$, but it was not promised that if $\inf_{b}d(a,B)\le d(a,b)$ then $\inf_{b}d(a',B)\le d(a',b)$ for the same $b$. Is that correct?

Comment: Your proof is correct. You're able to say WLOG because $A$ and $B$ are symmetric in this statement. In other words, if you switched the letters $A$ and $B$ everywhere, the statement would be equivalent. But that would not be true if you only assumed $A$ was bounded.

Comment: Or another perspective: $\sup_{a \in A}d(a,B)$ is always bounded whenever $A$ is bounded, and $\sup_{b \in B}d(b,A)$ is always bounded whenever $B$ is bounded.